# Why is the output different in both cases comparing floats

Tags: python, c, floating-point, precision, equality

**PYTHON PROGRAM**:

```
a = 0.2
if a == 0.2:
    print('*')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
*
```

**C PROGRAM**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    float a = 0.2;
    if(a == 0.2)
    {
        puts("*");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

Why is the output different in both cases? Is there a difference between the working of `==` operator?

Comment: In the `a == 0.2` in C, 0.2 is a _double_ while a is a _float_. Change it to `if(a == 0.2f) { .. }`. If that works / changes the behavior, search for "Is floating point math broken?"

Comment: [Very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Short summary: Don't ever do "exact comparison" using floating point values. Always use an *epsilon*.

Comment: Also, it's often hard to do direct comparison between different languages with different semantics. Even for small limited areas where syntax might seem the same, the behavior might be vastly different.

Comment: Alse [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: @Some programmer dude Not even in Python?

Comment: @NSR No not even in Python can it be reliable. Lets say you have made two different functions that take different input and do some calculation on the input. Using a specific set of inputs should mathematically produce an exact equal result, but due to inaccuracies in representation and possibly compounded rounding errors, the two results are not *exactly* equal, just very close.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Yeah, but while printing Python just approximates, right?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "Don't ever do "exact comparison" using floating point values. Always use an epsilon." is an overstatement.  Comment space too small for a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the types float and double have different width reserved for the mantissa. The type double can represent a floating number more precisely. In this case that matters as 0.2 can't be represented exactly and has a very slightly different representation when stored as a double vs. a float.

In the condition

```
if(a == 0.2)
```

the left operand has the type float while the right operand has the type double, as the default type of a number literal with a "." in C is a double.

So change the declaration the following way

```
double a = 0.2;
```

Or alternatively change the condition like

```
if(a == 0.2f)
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    float a1 = 0.2;

    if ( a1 == 0.2f )
    {
        puts( "*" );
    }

    double a2 = 0.2;

    if ( a2 == 0.2 )
    {
        puts( "*" );
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
*
*
```